# How to actually clone a div but the duplicated div has different content

Tags: javascript, html

I know how to duplicate div but the question is how can I make another duplicated div a different text.
Let's say I have a JSON file with the different contents that looks like this.
I will call the first file game1.json.

```json
{
    "game": {
        "name": "Something...",
        "description": "smol"
    }
}
```

And the second one I call it game2.json

```json
{
    "game": {
        "name": "Hello World",
        "description": "Hi"
    }
}
```

The main JSON code will parse those 2 JSON for the divs

```json
{
    "library": {
        "game1": "apps/game1.json",
        "game2": "apps/game2.json"
    }
}
```

After the parse is complete, I wanna duplicate a div of game1 for game2 but with a different content as described from game2.json. The problem is, how do I do it?

Comment: Please, provide the HTML, JS code.

Answer (score 0):

Create html template with div id and name from json key game1 and game2
So two div will be created with id and name as game1 for first div and game2 for second div
Contents of div will be from json file

Comment: What happens when a users requests to create a new JSON? So, the other JSON like will be parsed and have to create another one? That would be a hassle